# Access downloaded files via ajax in Cordova on Windows

Tags: ajax, cordova, win-universal-app

I'm currently working on migrating an ios-Cordova app to Windows (10) Universal App.

In the app I'm loading a xml and parse it with XSLT. The xml is located in the app-sandbox the xsl files in the program directory. I load both it via ajax which works fine on ios.

On windows the call fails.

```
var xmlurl = cordova.file.applicationStorageDirectory+'localState/cordova/';
   xmlurl += 'my.xml';
   //xmlurl => ms-appx:///localState/cordova/my.xml
   $.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: xmlurl,
       dataType. "xml",
       async: false,
       success: function(xmlData){},
       error: function(XHMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
           // textStatus => error, errorThrown => Access denied

      });
```

For cross site support I added

```
$.support.cors = true;
```

My Content Secruity Policy

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: ms-appdata: ms-appx: ms-appx-web: 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
```

I hope someone can help to get this running on windows. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure that the file exists? Any error trace in console?

Comment: I'm sure the file exists but not 100 percent sure if the path is correct    
C:\Users\JB\AppData\Local\Packages\<APP_ID>\LocalState\cordova\my.xml is the location of the file. 
On the cordova page cordova.file.applicationStorageDirectory should link to the app-data dir. But that should start with ms-appdata:///.

Comment: Additional: VisualStudio exits with:
Exception was thrown at line 8623, column 6 in ms-appx-web://<APP-DIR>/www/jscript/lib/jquery.2.1.1.js

0x80070005 - JavaScript runtime error: Access denied

Comment: Cant you the existence of fail in some file explorer? Also did you alerted the xmlurl to see the value?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:

1. There is a bug in cordova for windows the applicationStorageDirectory points to "ms-appx:///", but it should point to "ms-appdata:///". I submited a pull request to github.
2. The windows directory localState/ can't be used directly. To used that directory in cordova your path should be local/

So the correct path is "ms-appdata:///local/cordova/my.xml" instead of "ms-appx:///localState/cordova/my.xml".